# Cargar columnas tipo Combobox en datagridview con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

vengo con una consulta en la cual haciendo uso de `Entity Framework` realizo la carga de mis datos en un datagridview pero ahora debido a un requerimiento adicional en esa carga en el datagrid necesita colocar 3 columnas tipo combobox, como podría realizarlo ya que se carga directamente los datos?

```
 public void Obtener_Presupuesto(String sValue, DataGridView dataGridPre, TextBox pordscsub, Label totdscsub,
       TextBox portarsub, Label tottarsub, Label total)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
            {
                var pre = db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO.Where(a => a.PRE_COD == sValue).Select(x => new
                {
                    x.PRE_COD,
                    x.PRE_NOM_PAC,
                    x.PRE_NOM_ODON,
                    x.PRE_RUT,
                    x.PRE_DEN_PAC,
                    x.PRE_PIE_DEN,
                    x.PRE_TRA_PAC,
                    x.PRE_VAL_PRE,
                    x.PRE_VAL_POR,
                    x.PRE_VAL_DES,
                    x.PRE_VAL_SUB,
                    x.PRE_VAL_POR_DSC_SUB,
                    x.PRE_VAL_TOT_DSC_SUB,
                    x.PRE_VAL_TOT,
                    x.PRE_ID,
                    x.PRE_ELA_PRE,
                    x.PRE_EST_REA
                }
                ).OrderBy(a => a.PRE_ID).ToList();
                if (pre.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridPre.DataSource = pre;                     
                    dataGridPre.AutoResizeColumns();
                    dataGridPre.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Anteriormente envía primero a llamar el método para rellenar el `Datagridvieew` y posteriormente hacia el llenado del combo de la siguiente manera.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn = dataGridPre.Columns["PRE_PIE_DEN"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            comboboxColumn.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Dentadura();
            comboboxColumn.DisplayMember = "DENT_NOM";
            comboboxColumn.ValueMember = "DENT_NOM";
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Y los datos de esos combobox de donde salen?

Comment: @Yussef actualice la pregunta y añadí de donde sacas los datos de combo